# Download image from picturebox.image in c#.net desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, image, desktop-application, picturebox

I am developing a desktop application in which I want to doing a particular task i.e. **Save The Image In Database**, **Fetch The Image From Database And Show In PictureBox** and **Download The Image and save in folder From Picturebox Tool**

Here is the task code,

1. **Save The Image In Database**, in that I am using **ImageToBase64** function to save in database in a string format. like : `ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`

ImageToBase64 Function Code :

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now for fetch the image from database and show image in picturebox

```
picturebox1.image = Base64ToImage(dtSelStock.Rows[0]["DesignImage"].ToString())
```

Base64ToImage Function Code:

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    if (base64String != "")
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
          imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, these two task working perfectly. But the thrid and last task is to save image in folder from picturebox. I tried some of code but didnt working properly, infact showing error i.e.

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("D\\Image\\'" + pictureBox1.Image + "'", ImageFormat.JPEGImage);
```

Comment: update your question to provide the error\exception

Comment: @BrettCaswell edited. Please review it.

Comment: you should also be able to minimize this code to reproduce it easier with just `pictureBox2.image = Base64ToImage(ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg));` removing reference to database\datatable notions for reproducible, right?

Comment: @BrettCaswell actually I am fetching data in datatable by sql query and showing image in picturebox from that datatable, but its working perfectly not an issue about that,

Comment: You're not providing a [mcve], nor any specific info about whatever error you're getting, so the question should be closed. That said, based on what you did post, you failed to include the `:` character after the drive letter. And _that_ said, it's really wrong to be saving from the `PictureBox`. You should be saving the exact bytes you originally stored in the DB. Otherwise, every time you save the image, you're going to reduce quality a little bit more (since you're saving as JPEG).

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet reproduces your issue.

```
   var dataString = ImageToBase64(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   pictureBox2.Image = Base64ToImage(dataString);
   pictureBox2.Image.Save("D\\Images\\'" + pictureBox2.Image + "'", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

which relates to `"D\\Image\\'" + pictureBox1.Image + "'"`

I received the following exception stacktrace when running these snippets

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\brcaswell\Source\Repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 25
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\brcaswell\Source\Repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Program.cs:line 19
```

it isn't a valid filepath and\or directory doesn't exist.

this will correct it

```cs
   var filePath = @"D:\Images\";
   Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
   pictureBox2.Image.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, $"'{pictureBox2.Image}'"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

---

However, you should note that `'{pictureBox2.Image}'` will result in the Type's `toString` and will be `'System.Drawing.Bitmap'`as the filename.  You should correct that and include a file extension

```
Path.Combine(filePath, "myImage.jpeg")
```

---

Also, as @'Peter Duniho' mentioned in his comment on this question, you should consider saving this image file in a manner unrelated to the graphic context of the picture box control.

---

Additionally, you should consider saving images as binary `byte[]` in the database, not as base64 string representations.